# I'm building a counter, how do I update a list of dictionaries from with in a for loop (python)

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, dataframe, counter, gantt-chart

I'm counting the number of overlapping tasks, by teams from a Gantt chart with the idea to plot team workload as a time series.

process wise:

I'm counting the number of overlapping tasks for each day between a start and end date by each team in dictionaries dedicated to each team and then creating a Dataframe at the end (kinda like a sumif in excel (I'm learning k))

imported data structure (df) is something like the below:

```
Task Startdate EndDate SomeotherAttribute Team
```

I've got some working code where I use a series of for loops and then internally some if statements to update the dictionaries 1 by 1. something like:

```
if team =="teamA":
    count

if team =="teamB":
    count
```

etc

However, this is quite cumbersome and I would like to loop through a list of the below dictionaries

```
#create blank dictionary
teamA= {}
teamB= {}
teamC= {}
teamD= {}
teamE= {}
teamF= {}

teamlist=[teamA,teamB,teamC,teamD,teamE,teamF]

#for each item test to see if test date is between start and finish
for date in testrange:
    for i in df.index:
        for team in teamlist:
            if df.iloc[i,4]==team:
                if date>df.iloc[i,1] and date<df.iloc[i,2]:
                    if date in team.keys():
                        team[date] += 1
                    else:
                        team[date] = 1
```

While I do not get any errors. These dictionaries don't get updated as expected. I think I am doing something incorrectly in the definition of the *teamlist* list?

Any pointers would be great

Comment: if I change 

            if df.iloc[i,4]==team:
to
            if df.iloc[i,4]=="teamA":

it sort of works, the dictionaries get updated, but still not correctly (same values in all dictionaries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.iloc[i,4]==team` will compare `df.iloc[i,4]` against the *reference to* (!) the dict that you have defined above. That comparison can never succeed.

Also, that reference does not know the name of the variable it's assigned to. I am sure you want to compare against the team name, i.e. a string.

Let's use a dict that has keys ("names") and values (nested dicts):

```
datesByTeam = {
    "teamA": {}
    "teamB": {}
    "teamC": {}
    "teamD": {}
    "teamE": {}
    "teamF": {}
}

for date in testrange:
    for i in df.index:
        for name, team in datesByTeam.items():
            if df.iloc[i,4] == name:
                if date > df.iloc[i,1] and date < df.iloc[i,2]:
                    if date in team.keys():
                        team[date] += 1
                    else:
                        team[date] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: When I try this I get a ValueError on "for name, team in datesByTeam:"

_"ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"_

I'm at the edge of my understanding, so any tips would be helpful

Comment: I'm sorry, it needs to be `for name, teams in datesByTeam.items()` of course.

Comment: no need to be sorry, thanks very much for helping.

I think I still need some more study in datacamp

Comment: Since I have no idea of how your dataframe looks like - does it work?

Comment: Great, good to hear it's working! (In this case you should mark the answer as accepted, too)

Comment: so by writing "for name, team in datesByTeam.items():"

This is "for key, value in dictionary.items():"? Just confirming my understanding

Comment: Yes, exactly. I tend to use speaking variable names, and `name, team` has more meaning than `key, value`.